# ASUS Sabertooth P67 WOL

Tags: motherboard, wake-on-lan

Anyone using the Asus Sabertooth P67 motherboard that can confirm if Wake-on-LAN is supported with the onboard ethernet adapter?

I have downloaded the manual but I get the impression that WOL only works if I install a network card in the PCI or PCIe port as I can't find any instructions in the manual on how to enable WOL for the onboard ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 2):

yes, the wol works fine with P67.  Enable in bios first though. The bios doesn`t specific say WOL, read carefully all the options and explanations on the right side.

I had some problems myself with this until i used fusion WOL, works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As described in this blog post http://ryans-bliggity-blog.blogspot.de/2012/05/asus-p9x79-wake-on-lan-wol.html you have to enable `Advanced \ APM \ Power On By PCIE/PCI`

[image: image showing my bios/efi with the options to activate]